# ImportError: cannot import name 'NNDescent'

Tags: python, error-handling

This is the only line of code I'm trying to run:

```
import umap.umap_ as UMAP
```

These are the relevant packages: umap-learn-0.5.3, scipy-1.8.9, python- 3.10.4, numba -0.55.1, llvmlite -0.38.0.

I kept getting errors with umap so I made a new environment and installed all umap related packages at once & got those ^. But,
now this is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_23812/2055225328.py in <module>
----> 1 import umap.umap_ as UMAP
      2 #import umap

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\umap\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from warnings import warn, catch_warnings, simplefilter
----> 2 from .umap_ import UMAP
      3 
      4 try:
      5     with catch_warnings():

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\umap\umap_.py in <module>
     45 )
     46 
---> 47 from pynndescent import NNDescent
     48 from pynndescent.distances import named_distances as pynn_named_distances
     49 from pynndescent.sparse import sparse_named_distances as pynn_sparse_named_distances

ImportError: cannot import name 'NNDescent' from 'pynndescent' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Delete the question and update the old one. Did you install `pynndescent`?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Yes I did, pynndescent -0.5.4

Comment: Can you post the files code? why you use `.` in `from .umap_ import UMAP`? Did you use `conda install -c conda-forge pynndescent` to install it? I have installed it using anaconda prompt and it works fine, so you do something wrong.